# python ssl wrap_socket connect faied to a secure websocket service

Tags: python, websocket, ssl-certificate

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM),server_hostname=hostname)
conn.connect((hostname,443))
```

I just want to get the certificate info from a secure websocket service.
It returns this error message：

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

i found a new solution to solve it

```
certfile="/tmp/cert.pem" #your CA chain
context.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_verify_locations(certfile)
```